# C# Json Deserialize exception ("Error converting value "id" to type 'Eng_Tab.JsonData'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 5.")

Tags: c#, json

I'm new to Json with C#. I`m trying to deserialize JSON string to display to into a data grid.
I succeeded to get the JSON string from the server but when trying to  deserialize  it, it throws this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
>   "id" to type 'Eng_Tab.JsonData'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 5. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String
>   to Eng_Tab.JsonData.

This is the data class:

> public class JsonData
>       {
>           public int id { get; set; }
>           public string lec { get; set; }
>           public string sec1 { get; set; }
>           public string sec2 { get; set; }
>           public string sec3 { get; set; }
>           public string sec4 { get; set; }
>           public string sec5 { get; set; }
>           public string sec6 { get; set; }
>           public string sec7 { get; set; }
>           public string sec8 { get; set; }
>           public string sec9 { get; set; }
>           public string sec10 { get; set; }
>
> ```
>     public int h { get; set; }
>     public int h1 { get; set; }
>     public int h2 { get; set; }
>     public int h3 { get; set; }
>     public int h4 { get; set; }
>     public int h5 { get; set; }
>     public int h7 { get; set; }
>     public int h8 { get; set; }
>     public int h9 { get; set; }
>     public int h10 { get; set; }
>
>     public int m { get; set; }
>     public int m1 { get; set; }
>     public int m2 { get; set; }
>     public int m3 { get; set; }
>     public int m4 { get; set; }
>     public int m5 { get; set; }
>     public int m6 { get; set; }
>     public int m7 { get; set; }
>     public int m8 { get; set; }
>     public int m9 { get; set; }
>     public int m10 { get; set; }
>
> }
> ```

Here is the Json string:

> ["id":"1","h":"7","m":"0","lec":"","h1":"0","m1":"0","sec1":"","h2":"10","m2":"0","sec2":"Abdelrahman
>   Mohamed401119343000","h3":"10","m3":"0","sec3":"Abdelrahman
>   Mohamed401119343000","h4":"5","m4":"0","sec4":"A401119343000","h5":"5","m5":"0","sec5":"A401119343000","h6":"5","m6":"0","sec6":"A401119343000","h7":"5","m7":"0","sec7":"A401119343000","h8":"5","m8":"0","sec8":"A401119343000","h9":"18","m9":"0","sec9":"Abdelrahman
>   Mohamed401119343000","h10":"0","m10":"0","sec10":"set sec"]

and this is my C# code:

> string qry = "de=e1&id=1";
>
> WebRequest request =WebRequest.Create("the php link"+qry);
>
> WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
>
> StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),Encoding.ASCII);
>
> string jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
>
> jsonData = jsonData.Replace("{", "[").Replace("}","]");
>
> MessageBox.Show(jsonData);
>
> List`<JsonData>` result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`<List<JsonData>>`(jsonData);
>
> metroGrid1.DataSource = result;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need on object of type `JsonData` in Json string to deserialize. Thus your JSON string should look like `[{"ABC":"PQR", ...}]`